# MySQL filter out subset by group by

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, compare

1A

```
a  b  c

1  1  6
1  1  7
2  1  8
2  2  2
2  2  9
```

B

```
a  b  c

1  1  7
2  2  9
```

I want to filter out a subset of A

```
a  b  c

1  1  6
2  2  2
```

I am intend to join two tables by group by column **a, b**

such that to select the value in column **c** is less than the **c** value in table **B**, which is the desired subset.

But don't know how to implement this.

Comment: There might be multiple rows with "c is less than the c value in table B". But since you want to "group by column a, b" you need to decide which `c` to take.

Comment: Sorry I typed it wrong, column b in B should be 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.* FROM A INNER JOIN B
ON A.a=B.b AND A.c<B.c;
```

See [MySQL Join Made Easy](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) tutorial.

Comment: Thank you. Also could you show me how to do it with the way of group by as my work might be a little bit complex than the example.